# Could not find main class error when running a java wsdl client

Tags: java, wsdl

I have written the following code, which is meant to be a client wsdl for http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx?WSDL:

```
package time;
class Client {
 public static void main(String args[]){
        TimeService service = new TimeService();
        TimeServiceSoap port= service.getTimeServiceSoap();
        String result = port.getTimeZoneTime("UTC+10");
        System.out.println("Time is "+result);
 }
}
```

But when I try to run it with java I get the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin>java client.Client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: client/Client
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.Client
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: client.Client.  Program will exit.
```

Does this error mean I should be importing any classes?

Answer (score 2):

The main class you wrote is `time.Client`, but you are trying to run `client.Client`. Better run it like this:

```
java time.Client
```

If this does not help, then you have a classpath problem - java cannot find the main class in the classpath. Set the classpath with `-classpath` [option](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#options):

```
java -classpath classes-directory;list-of-jar-files time.Client
```

Comment: java time.Client was the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the classpath:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin>java -cp . client.Client
```